# Is there a way to collapse only files in VS Code’s explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-code, file-organization

I work on a large project where large portions of the files are not in “leaf nodes”. There are many directories with subdirectories and a large number of files as well. This poor organization has made navigating the file tree an onerous exercise to say the least.

I’m wondering whether there is a convenient solution, native or in an extension, that allows the VS Code explorer sidebar to by default not show all the files in a directory that either has subdirectories in it or has them open. Instead it could have an item called *Files* which could be separately expanded/collapsed as if it were a subdirectory.

The program WinDirStat uses this approach by default, here is an image for reference. Notice how there is a section labeled “Files” to reduce clutter.

[image: WinDirStat GUI]

If this doesn’t exist as a setting or an extension, I suppose that’s not a bad idea for a project.

Comment: writing an extension with a View that does this is not very difficult if you only want to browse the tree and open files, and the text `not show all the files in a directory that either has subdirectories in it or has them open` is pretty vague if only you want to show the files in a virtual folder. You can add this view to the explorer bar, or do a feature request at VSC github issues

Comment: I just thought instead of always collapsing the files, there could be some logic to leave the virtual folder expanded if certain user-configurable conditions were met. Obviously if a folder has no subdirectories, it probably doesn’t make sense to have the files collapsed.